# How do you draw a direction field for 2x2 matrix?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

I understand $AX = X'$ and by doing so, you get both equation for derivative of $x_1 and $x_2$.

When I make a $x_1$ and $x_2$ plot, I am confused regarding which derivative of $x_1$ or $x_2$ to choose?

Say I want to create a direction field for 
$$X' = \begin{pmatrix} 
-1/2& 1 \\ -1 & -1/2 
\end{pmatrix}  X$$ 
How would I plot a direction field of $x_1$ and $x_2$? $X$ matrix contains $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Um, you need to explain a lot more of the context of what you're trying to do. As your question stands it is very difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Alright Say I want to create a direction field for x' = (-1/2 1 -1 -1/2) X Where (-1/2 1 -1 -1/2) is A matrix. How would I plot a direction field of x1 and x2? X matrix contains x1 and x2.

Answer (score 7):

You don't choose any derivatives. The direction field consists of vectors $A\vec x$ where $\vec x$ ranges over the plane. For example, at $(2,4)$ you draw the vector 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
-1/2& 1 \\ -1 & -1/2 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
2 \\ 4
\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 
3 \\ -4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

(One usually scales down these vectors; keeping their direction but not the length. Otherwise the plot would be a mess of overlapping arrows.)

You could go on, picking some points with convenient (small integer) coordinates. 
A more sophisticated approach is to look for *nullclines*: the lines along with one of two components of $A\vec x$ is zero. Then sketch the field within each of four angles formed by the  nullclines.

Or just use a computer, e.g., [Desmos vector field generator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eijhparfmd):

[image: field]